# Error message on Workflows page - unable to manually start a workflow

Tags: workflow, error

After some recent server patching and a security McAfee update I'm getting the following error when opening Workflows page on an individual item. This was found using the corelation id. Can anyone advise what the problem is, and/or suggest a fix?

Getting Error Message for Exception

```
 System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: A response was returned that did not come from the Workflow Manager. Status code = 403:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head>  <title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 403.6 - Forbidden</title>  <style type="text/css">  <!--  body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#CBE1EF;} code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}  .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}  pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}  ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 40px;}  ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}  fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}  .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}  legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}  legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px
-12px;_margin-top:0px;   border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px solid #969696;   border-bottom:1px solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}  a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}  a:hover{text-decoration:none;}  h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}  h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}  h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}  h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;  }#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;   color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;  }#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}  .summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} .config_source{background:#fff5c4;}  .content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;  }#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;  }#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;  }#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;   background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid
#C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;   font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;  }#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}  table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}  td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;border:none;}  th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:normal;}  thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;  }#details-right th{width:20%;}  table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{background-color:#ebebeb;}  .highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}  .clear{clear:both;}  .preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
-->  </style>    </head>  <body>  <div id="header"><h1>Server Error in Application "WORKFLOW MANAGEMENT SITE"</h1></div>  <div id="server_version"><p>Internet Information Services 7.5</p></div>  <div id="content">  <div class="content-container">   <fieldset><legend>Error Summary</legend>    <h2>HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden</h2>    <h3>The IP address from which you are browsing is not permitted to access the requested Web site.</h3>   </fieldset>  </div>  <div class="content-container">   <fieldset><legend>Detailed Error Information</legend>    <div id="details-left">     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">      <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>IpRestrictionModule</td></tr>      <tr><th>Notification</th><td>BeginRequest</td></tr>      <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0</td></tr> <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>0x80070005</td></tr>           </table>    </div>    <div id="details-right">     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">      <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>http://myservername:12291/SharePoint/default/0c7ac9b9-55a3-4469-b048-220fcb4bc808/52f5fbb7-9620-4b22-ac1f-5b607c3b16b2/$Workflows/$Instances?$skip=0&amp;$top=100&amp;monitoringParameter=ae29f83d-ca1d-4e02-b65b-7050dc0d027c</td></tr> <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\WFWebRoot\SharePoint\default\0c7ac9b9-55a3-4469-b048-220fcb4bc808\52f5fbb7-9620-4b22-ac1f-5b607c3b16b2\$Workflo Client ActivityId : 137a7d9d-cb7e-10b3-187e-0bcc3a1a79cf. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.ValidateServerResponseHeader(HttpWebResponse response, WebException webException, Guid traceActivityId)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.GetExceptionForErrorResponse(WebException webException, Guid traceActivityId)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InstanceManager.GetInternal(Int32 skip, Int32 count, String workflowName, WorkflowInstanceStatus workflowStatus, IDictionary`2 activationMetadataFilter)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.EnumerateByMonitoringParameter(Guid monitoringParameter, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean checkPermissions, Nullable`1 secondaryMonitoringParameter)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(Guid listId, Int32 itemId, Int32 offset)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(Guid listId, Int32 itemId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPageBase.ConstructStatusArraysWF4(ArrayList running, ArrayList completed, Boolean onlyMyWorkflows)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.ConstructStatusArrays() at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

Each client has a unique IP address. If the server defines a list of IP addresses that are not allowed to access the site and the IP address you are using is on this list, you will receive the error message.

This is a feature that grants or denies specific users access to a Web site, directory, or file.

**Resolution**

To resolve this problem, follow these steps.

1. Using the Internet Service Manager (Microsoft Management Console), open the Internet Information Server (IIS) snap-in and select the Web site reporting the 403.6 error. Right-click the Web site, virtual directory, or file where the error is occurring. Click Properties to display the property sheet for that item.
2. Select the appropriate Directory Security or File Security property page. Under IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions, click Edit.
3. In the IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions dialog box, if the Denied Access option is selected, then add the IP address, network ID, or domain of the computer that requires access to the exceptions list.

   In the IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions dialog box, if the Granted Access option is selected, then remove the IP address, network ID, or domain of the computer that requires access to the exceptions list.

**Important**

- When you set security properties for a specific Web site, you automatically set the same security properties for directories and files belonging to that site, unless the security properties of the individual directories and files have been previously set.
- Your Web server will prompt you for permission to reset the properties of individual directories and files when you attempt to set security properties for your Web site. If you choose to reset these properties, your previous security settings will be replaced by the new settings. The same condition applies when you set security properties for a directory containing subdirectories or files with previously set security properties.

**Notes**

- By default, some sites are only granted access from the IP address 127.0.0.1, which corresponds to the computer name localhost and is considered a different address/name than the NetBIOS or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the Web server. To access a site restricted to localhost, you must be at the console of the computer with the localhost restriction.
- Computers accessing your server across proxy servers will appear to have the IP address of the proxy server.
- Restricting by domain name is not recommended because it decreases the performance of your Web server by forcing the Web server to perform a reverse DNS lookup for each connection to that site. In addition to increasing the load on the Web server, reverse lookups can also result in unexpected denials.

Comment: Which IP addresses are needed specifically for a SharePoint Workflow Management Site? For instance, do we need to include the other servers in our farm? Or just the IP addresses of our clients (Intranet users).

Comment: Please see the notes

Comment: We need to add other server's IP Address in our farm

Comment: Thanks Hardik. On more question. Should this include our SQL server? Or just our application/web servers?

Comment: Only app or web server

Comment: I don't think this is the issue since the list of IP addresses did not change under IP Address and Domain Name Restrictions settings. We were, and still are allowing the other web server and local server.

Comment: Have you identified the resolution for your issue?

Comment: No not yet. I inherited this farm and so I'm not that familiar with the correct configuration. Is it normal that the Worflow Management Site is in "Stopped" state in IIS on the app server? I just noticed this.

Comment: We finally figured this out. Even though in IIS our two "Allow" IPs under IP And Domsin Restrictions where displaying as "Allow", if we clicked to edit the IP listing for the other server it showed as defaulting to "Deny". We removed the IP and added it again as "Allow". Reset IIS and voila! How this happened I still don't know.